# where is T_SafeVector.h?

Tags: c, platform-sdk

From what Platform SDK?
Which version?
Where can be downloaded? link

Thanks.

Comment: Though I don't want to go overboard with my comment, my earlier answer is correct! Please mark what other information you are seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T_SafeVector.h is provided by Microsoft as part of what used to be called Platform SDK. Now Platform SDK has been superseded by the Windows SDK

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924

Windows SDK = Platform SDK + .NET Framework SDK